# Transcode SVG to JPEG

Tags: svg, jpeg, padding, batik

[image: the original image was svg, but i can only upload png-format not svg-format]

my picture in SVG format include the latest data 122.6 but in JPEG format the last data point is 122.1

How can I convert the image in svg-format to jpeg-format without the lost of the latest data
renderer ?
padding margins ?
size ?

What is wrong in my code ??

best ghost

```
package helix;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.JPEGTranscoder;
import org.apache.fop.svg.PDFTranscoder;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
import org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.codec.*;


public class genesisMATPIsvg2jpg {
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
                
        //Step -1: We read the input SVG document into Transcoder Input
        String svg_URI_input = new File(basePath + "/var/gWebClient/Materialkostenindex2015=100.svg").toURL().toString();
        TranscoderInput input_svg_image = new TranscoderInput(svg_URI_input);        
        //Step-2: Define OutputStream to JPG file and attach to TranscoderOutput
        OutputStream jpg_ostream = new FileOutputStream(basePath + "/var/gWebClient/Materialkostenindex2015=100.jpeg");
        TranscoderOutput output_jpg_image = new TranscoderOutput(jpg_ostream);              
        // Step-3: Create JPEGTranscoder and define hints
        JPEGTranscoder my_converter = new JPEGTranscoder();
        
        Object jpegQuality1 = new Float(800);
        Object jpegQuality2 = new Float(600);
        
        my_converter.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, jpegQuality1);
        my_converter.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, jpegQuality2);
        
        my_converter.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_QUALITY,new Float(0.9));
        // Step-4: Write output
        my_converter.transcode(input_svg_image, output_jpg_image);
        // Step 5- close / flush Output Stream
        jpg_ostream.flush();
        jpg_ostream.close();        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the SVG and the generated JPEG file?

Comment: https://jgumainz-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/personal/giehp005_uni-mainz_de/Documents/Materialkostenindex2015=100.jpeg?csf=1&web=1&e=esRW0W  https://jgumainz-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/r/personal/giehp005_uni-mainz_de/Documents/Materialkostenindex2015=100.svg?csf=1&web=1&e=eugdUH

Comment: Accessing these files requires a Microsoft account, and possibly even additional permission. I cannot access them.

Comment: Hi Codo ! how can i send you the graphics ? e-mail or an other way ?

Comment: They need to be accessible for everybody. This is a knowledge site, not a discussion forum and certainly not a bilateral communication between you and me. You should be able to add the JPEG image directly to the question like you added the PNG image. And if the SVG file isn't too big, you can add it like code to the question as well.

Comment: Once again !!!!    https://jgumainz-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/giehp005_uni-mainz_de/EdiTd6P5kBtMqcq3CL-loiEBesEYqZliJyfHYeehozOjwQ?e=I0UWm7      https://jgumainz-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/giehp005_uni-mainz_de/EQEv5ooQ-f5EqsFWbgjtgEYBCuGLeoTllDGVLd-pJz7tig?e=zGhHUW

Comment: The JPEG image is 0 bytes long.

Comment: https://jgumainz-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/giehp005_uni-mainz_de/EQEv5ooQ-f5EqsFWbgjtgEYBCuGLeoTllDGVLd-pJz7tig?e=VbL5yX    the file size is 64.4 KB

Comment: I can now open the JPEG file and I can see the missing line segment. But I've run the same code on my machine (macOS, JDK 17) and it works just fine.

Comment: Hi Codo! Thanks a lot for the Support …i use linux ubuntu 16.04 and jdk 1.8 …perhaps time to upgrade. - ghost